# sed/awk to replace in a loop

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have a file called "demo" that has names in our DNS.

I'm trying to loop through each line and replace the "names" with "names and ip address" (as a way of verifying dns queries)

So far I have this but no luck on sed or awk command.
Help appreciated.

Thanks.

### demo

```
1   10.1.22.117   qa/testing 
2   172.16.1.5   dc/vpn
3   10.102.99.2   devtest/testing
```

"diggs" has an alias that yields one line output.

### desired output

```
1   10.1.22.117==qa==qa   qa/testing
2   172.16.1.5==dc==dc   dc/vpn
3   10.102.99.2==devtest==devtest   devtest/testing
```

### process.sh

```
for i in $(awk -F "   " '{print $2}' demo)
do
        bothR="$i==$(diggs $i)"
        echo "$i==$bothR"
        echo "#######"
        #what sed?
        #sed -i "s/$i/$bothR/" demo        
        #sed '0,/"$i"/s//"$bothR"/' demo                 
done
```

Comment: please add sample input and expected output...  it is not clear why you need loop when sed/awk will anyway read entire input file line by line... and awk by default splits input line on white-space...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very unclear as to what you're trying to do, but is this what you're thinking? No need for getting `sed` or `awk` involved.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line; do
    echo $line $(dig +short $line|head -1) >> output.txt
done < ifile.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

No need for a loop, try this `awk` one-liner.

```
$cat file
1   10.1.22.117   qa 
2   172.16.1.5   dc
3   10.102.99.2   devtest
```

Do-

```
$awk '{print $1, $2 "=="$3"=="$3, $3}' file
```

Output-

```
1 10.1.22.117==qa==qa qa
2 172.16.1.5==dc==dc dc
3 10.102.99.2==devtest==devtest devtest
```

If you want to maintain the tabs in the output-

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"} {print $1, $2 "=="$3"=="$3, $3}' file
```

Comment: @SndLt there isn't the slightest clue in your question that THAT is what you're trying to do. Edit your question to really state your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -r 's#(.*\S+)(\s+)(\w+)/#\1==\3==\3\2\3/#' input.txt
```